# Matrix tree data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Recently I heard from professor in my university about such data structure as "matrix tree". I can understand *what* it is, but *where is it useful*?

I'll try to give short explanation for this structure:

We have a tree root - special node. Then we have left and right "children" (subtrees). Both are binary trees. And if there is no some numbers in the tree but we add their "descendants" then we add this missing numbers as parasitic (so subtrees is nearly full). In left tree all nodes are even numbers. Others are in right tree. And for N we can say that `N = 2^L(2*Y - 1)` where `N` - node value (even, in this case), `L` - level number and `Y` - position in level.

Example (even subtree):

```
     8
   /   \
  4     12
 / \    /\
2   6 10  14
```

If we exclude, for example, `4`, it become parasitic (special flag in node) and that's all.

Comment: Is this what you're talking about? [Matrix Trees](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/nandrysc/pub/Andrysco_EV10_MatrixTrees.pdf)

Comment: As I understand this article is about _representation_ trees (kd and octrees) through matrixes and this is not what I have described. But thank you nonetheless.